# Getting the result from procedure in laravel - removing the square brackets from the response

Tags: php, sql, arrays, stored-procedures, laravel

Here is my Procedure

```
$result = DB::select('call FastBooking(?,?)',array(Input::get('Lat'),Input::get('Long')));
return $result;
```

while i execute and trying to return the `$result` i am getting it as

```
[{"AutoId":4,"DriverId":4,"distance":103.81984745881},{"AutoId":3,"DriverId":3,"distance":373.5531833859},{"AutoId":1,"DriverId":1,"distance":7528.7211073364},{"AutoId":2,"DriverId":2,"distance":7560.0258965718}]
```

While i try to `print_r($result);` i am getting the following result

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [AutoId] => 4 [DriverId] => 4 [distance] => 103.81984745881 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [AutoId] => 3 [DriverId] => 3 [distance] => 373.5531833859 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [AutoId] => 1 [DriverId] => 1 [distance] => 7528.7211073364 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [AutoId] => 2 [DriverId] => 2 [distance] => 7560.0258965718 ) ) Tarrif is 1 Day is 4 Time is 4Current Date is 2015-02-26 - Count : 0
```

I just want to get the

```
{"AutoId":4,"DriverId":4,"distance":103.81984745881},{"AutoId":3,"DriverId":3,"distance":373.5531833859},{"AutoId":1,"DriverId":1,"distance":7528.7211073364},{"AutoId":2,"DriverId":2,"distance":7560.0258965718}
```

Which mean i don't want to get the square brackets outside,

How can i get like this ?

(Don't care about the decoding, i just want to remove the `[]` square brackets here)

Comment: You have an array of objects.  The brackets on the outside are necessary for decoding.

Comment: No, I don't decode this one directly, i have another set of objects where i will just insert into it, So i just need to remove `[]` for this case

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason why someone would want a string of broken json, but you can  try do something like this...

```
str_replace (array('[', ']'), '' , $data);
```

I'm not sure what you are using this data for but I highly suggest you keep valid json.

Comment: Getting the same result :( `:[{"AutoId":4,"DriverId":4,"distance":103.81984745881},{"AutoId":3,"DriverId":3,"distance":373.5531833859},{"AutoId":1,"DriverId":1,"distance":7528.7211073364},{"AutoId":2,"DriverId":2,"distance":7560.0258965718}]`